# Dynamically creating tables using information held in another table

Tags: sql

I want to create a table in sql using the columns details (name, data type etc.) stored in  anther table in the database.

Comment: Would you kindly formulate your question clearly using punctuation? Reading it like that makes it completely unclear as to what you want to achieve.

Comment: in pure sql?  or use a script? what db?

Comment: @user628347 you mean that the names of the fields of your new table are stored in another table?

Comment: yes its in another table how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the database you can use the information schema tables. They hold the information you are looking for. Look for the table that describes the columns.

Postgres: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/interactive/information-schema.html

MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

You can query these tables and use 'select into' to insert the results into your other table.

Answer (score 0):

One opinion is to create [CREATE TABLE](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlcreate.html) query and execute it in ADO.NET like shown here [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/CreatingDBProgrammaticallyMCB11282005064852AM/CreatingDBProgrammaticallyMCB.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code

CREATE TABLE new_table
AS
   SELECT *
     FROM old_table
    WHERE 1 = 2;

Comment: -1: The OP asked for a table with the names & data types of fields coming from another table, not to populate the new table with the data from the first.

Comment: ya i said the column information of the new table is stored as the values in the old table

Comment: in this case (1=2) you do not populate any data, it only creates the same structure